# How to implement different states of object in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

What's a compact and simple way to implement variants of object going through different states?
The complication is that for every state a new properties added to the same object.

A task executed and follow through states Created / Waiting / InProgress possible way would be
to define following classes

```
class Task(
  val type:         String,
  val make_request: () -> Void
)

class TaskWaitingExecution(
  val task:        Task,
  val retry_count: Int
)

class TaskInProgress(
  val task:       TaskWaitingExecution,
  val request_id: Int
) {
  val timer          = bon.timer()
}
```

And progress with steps

```
val task = Task("some_request', {})
val waiting = TaskWaitingExecution(task, 1)
val in_progress = TaskInProgress(waiting, 10)
```

But it's not ideal as accessing say `type` property would end up in

```
in_progress.task.task.type
```

Sadly there's no way to use implements by inhreitance `implement PreviousTask by task`
as it's not working for classes.

Is there a better way to express such logic?

Comment: This seems backwards to me. Shouldn't a `Task` have a `var state: TaskState` rather than the other way round? Where `interface TaskState` is implemented by `class WaitingExecution` and `class InProgress`.

Comment: @Thomas yes you can set `var state Enum.start, waiting, in-process`, but where are you going to keep the properties? You end up adding lots of nullable properties as they would make be assigned only at some points in the future. The problem is not state itself, but managing properties that's added in future states.

Comment: Who said anything about enums? I said `interface TaskState` but on second thought, [sealed classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sealed-classes.html) are perfect for this job.

Comment: @Thomas - I see, you mean different classes of state? how you going to keep track of properties? Like merging `type` and `retry_count` for `Waiting` state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn it inside out and put the status as a property of the `Task`:

```
class Task(
  val type:         String,
  val make_request: () -> Void,
  var status:       TaskStatus = null,
)
```

To store the status-specific fields, a [sealed class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sealed-classes.html) is perfect:

```
sealed class TaskStatus;

class WaitingExecution : TaskStatus (
  val retry_count: Int
)

class InProgress : TaskStatus (
  val request_id: Int
) {
  val timer          = bon.timer()
}
```

Usage:

```
val task = Task("some_request', {})
task.status = WaitingExecution(1)
task.status = InProgress(10)
```

You can do it with `val status` as well, but then you'd need to create a new `Task` object each time its status changes.

It's been a while since I last Kotlin'ed so there might be syntax errors, but I hope the idea is clear.

Comment: Thanks! Question about this line `task.status = InProgress(10)` - you loose the `WaitingExecution.retry_count` parameter. Is there a way to keep parameters of the previous states when switching to the next one?

Comment: Maybe use a stack of states? Or make `InProgress` a nullable field on `WaitingExecution`?

Comment: yea, I ended up with similar thing, stack of `in_progress.task.task.type` chain, and when there's more states it's even more complicated.

Comment: Actually, you are right, with your approach there will be much less nested fields, only the added fields will be nested, thanks!